# Changing camera Back to front while capturing the video cause a weird issue

Tags: ios, video, filter, camera

I am creating camera app which capture video using **SCRecorder**. I am trying to apply multiple filters to a video. I am changing Recorder's video configuration as below

```
func swipeableFilterView(_ swipeableFilterView: SCSwipeableFilterView, didScrollTo filter: SCFilter?) {
    selectedFilter = filter!
    recorder.videoConfiguration.filter = filter!
}
```

I am capturing video with **applying filters** when i change camera back to front then I am getting Black screen at right side as Bellowed Image:

[image]

with back camera it will works perfect

here is code of appendVideoSampleBuffer

```
- (void)appendVideoSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer toRecordSession:(SCRecordSession *)recordSession duration:(CMTime)duration connection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection completion:(void(^)(BOOL success))completion {
    @autoreleasepool {
        CVPixelBufferRef sampleBufferImage = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer);

        size_t bufferWidth = (CGFloat)CVPixelBufferGetWidth(sampleBufferImage);
        size_t bufferHeight = (CGFloat)CVPixelBufferGetHeight(sampleBufferImage);

        CMTime time = CMSampleBufferGetPresentationTimeStamp(sampleBuffer);
        SCFilter *filterGroup = _videoConfiguration.filter;
        SCFilter *transformFilter = [self _transformFilterUsingBufferWidth:bufferWidth bufferHeight:bufferHeight mirrored:
                                     _device == AVCaptureDevicePositionFront
                                     ];

            if (filterGroup == nil && transformFilter == nil) {
                [recordSession appendVideoPixelBuffer:sampleBufferImage atTime:time duration:duration completion:completion];
                return;
            }

        CVPixelBufferRef pixelBuffer = [recordSession createPixelBuffer];

        if (pixelBuffer == nil) {
            completion(NO);
            return;
        }

        CIImage *image = [CIImage imageWithCVPixelBuffer:sampleBufferImage];
        CFTimeInterval seconds = CMTimeGetSeconds(time);

            if (transformFilter != nil) {
                image = [transformFilter imageByProcessingImage:image atTime:seconds];
            }

            if (filterGroup != nil) {
                image = [filterGroup imageByProcessingImage:image atTime:seconds];
            }

        CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(pixelBuffer, 0);

        [_context render:image toCVPixelBuffer:pixelBuffer];

        [recordSession appendVideoPixelBuffer:pixelBuffer atTime:time duration:duration completion:^(BOOL success) {
            CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(pixelBuffer, 0);

            CVPixelBufferRelease(pixelBuffer);

            completion(success);
        }];
    }
}
```

I debugged the code and I think issue is with

```
     CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(pixelBuffer, 0);
```

any one please help me!

Comment: The issue is with drawing of the frame, probably due to different size of the frame between back and front cameras. Please provide the implementation of `[_context render:image toCVPixelBuffer:pixelBuffer];` method in order to have a better understanding

Comment: @DisableR You are right I had noticed that back and front camera's sizes are different